# Can I not use NAT?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, nat

I have a static internet IP address which I got from the ISP and I have to setup web server.

Since I have a static IP, Can/should I set the internet static IP on the Ubuntu server directly?

For example I have 2 network connections, 1st is internet IP, 2nd is used for LAN is it possible?

Domain provider support is recommending use the NAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* put your Ubuntu server directly on the internet.  But you need to understand that you would be exposing your server to all of the threats that are out there. Your provider recommends NAT because they know most home users don't have the system or networking knowledge to secure a server that's exposed to the internet. Now, NAT isn't the same thing as a security firewall, but most home NAT devices have basic security built in.

In short, you can do what you want, as long as you understand the risks and how to mitigate them.

Comment: As I prepare to install bigbluebutton. it says: "configure a fully qualified domain name (FQDN), such as bbb.example.com, that resolves to the external IP address of your server" am I right set my internet ip to the server?

Comment: I am not familiar with bigbluebutton. but my guess is its asking for the address of yuor website.